# unable to access executable in PATH from remote server

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn

I have an web application hosted with Django-gUnicorn-Nginx. The web app is working mostly fine and is accessible except for one functionality.

Recently, I added [pybedtools](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/index.html), a python wrapper package for [bedtools](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I have the binary executables of bedtools in the `PATH` variable. However, the server is unable to access this executable.

The error just reports
`intersectBed does not appear to be installed or on the path, so this method is disabled.  Please install a more recent version of BEDTools and re-import to use this method`

I have tested/reinstalled the latest versions locally and it works, but not in the server.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Has the webserver been restarted since you added that package?

Comment: Yes I restarted the webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good old print statements came to rescue!

The path variable passed on to the server instance somehow had only the defaults
`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin`.

I couldn't manage to export the location where `bedtools` is installed to the PATH. So I simply created a symlink of `bedtools` executable in my `/usr/local/bin`

Thanks for the suggestions Gerard.